Apache Camel Swift Converter
I'm trying to convert swift MT-MX using apache camel. I found: [APACHE CAMEL COMPONENT SWIFT MX][1] and i tried to use it:
@Component
public class MySpringBootRouter extends RouteBuilder {
    
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        
        from("file://inputDir?noop=true")
        .unmarshal().swiftMt()
        .to("file://output?fileName=test.xml"); 
    }
}

Is there a way to convert it directly to SwiftMX without going through the process. I did some research and found prowidesoftware translator but it's not free. If not, is there another way/library to convert it using camel?

What happens, if you simply remove the .convertBodyTo(String.class)? There is no need for converting it to a string first.

@Raphi1 it tells me that it cannot convert file to AbstractMX

The error message indicates, that you've generated an object of type com.prowidesoftware.swift.model.mt.mt1xx.MT103_STP (which you wanted to achieve with the unmarshal). Of course, you can not write this java object to a file.
You need to process the com.prowidesoftware.swift.model.mt.mt1xx.MT103_STP to something, the file endpoint can handle, aka you have to marshal it or something else. What do you want to achieve exactly?

@Raphi1 I want to convert MT to MX (XML)

As far as I can see, that is not, what the component is providing. There are both data formats (MX and MT) but they only can read text and convert it in a respective java object. You would need to implement the conversion from MT-object to MX-object on your own in a processor. After that (by creating a MX-body) you could call marshal().swiftMx() and write it to a file.
